# I'm able send email via Thunderbird, but not via my own app. The email settings are identical

Tags: email, postfix, starttls

I have my Postfix server. I can send email via it with no problem using Thunderbird. For smtp I have:

```
port - 587
Normal Password
STARTTLS
```

However, I can't send an email through the same server via my own app. The settings are these:

```
server: "mail.my_server.com",
username: "aaa@my_domain123.com",
password: "fdsafdsafdsfds"",
port: 587,
allowed_tls_versions: [:"tlsv1", :"tlsv1.1", :"tlsv1.2"],
retries: 5,
auth: :if_available

// tls: :always,
// ssl: true,
// no_mx_lookups: false, # can be `true`
// auth: :always,
```

I have an exception:

```
450 4.7.1 Client host rejected: cannot find your reverse hostname: 11.22.33.44
```

Where 11.22.33.44 is my external IP of my home computer

**How can I be able to send email from *home computer* via Thunderbird, but not my own app running on the same home computer, using the same server and presumably - settings?**

Comment: Please post the output of `postconf -n`.

Comment: Are you sure the authentication works? I *suspect* the server is configured to allow any client that is authenticated, despite not having reverse DNS. So if you are rejected because of not having reverse DNS, the implication is that you're not authenticated.

Comment: @Halfgaar I've played with the settings futher. Now I have: `SASL LOGIN authentication failed: UGFzc3dvcmQ6` and `SASL PLAIN authentication failed: UGFzc3dvcmQ6
` --> and this is different from I have of Thunderbird `sasl_method=PLAIN, sasl_username=aaa@my_domain123.com`. why? Note that `UGFzc3dvcmQ6` isn't my pass, but something else

Comment: Can you post a (redacted) screenshot of your Thunderbird SMTP auth settings, and some more code of your app that shows sending of the actual mail?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to bet this is due to your app sending something like `localhost` or `localhost.localdomain` [in the EHLO](https://cr.yp.to/smtp/ehlo.html), or not sending an EHLO at all. Thunderbird is most likely sending a more appropriate value.

Can you please post the output from `/var/log/maillog` for both when you attempt to send mail from your application, and then when you send mail from Thunderbird?

A quick solution may be to remove [reject_unknown_helo_hostname](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#reject_unknown_helo_hostname) directive from the [smtpd_helo_restrictions](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_helo_restrictions) configuration. A more secure and probably just as quick solution would be to configure [mynetworks](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#mynetworks) and then use the [permit_mynetworks](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#permit_mynetworks) directive of the [smtpd_helo_restrictions](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_helo_restrictions) configuration.